# Updating a range of formulas using another range in the formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to update a range of cells at once that reference consecutive columns. Basically, the code I would use for a specific cell formula is this:

```
Range("C10").Formula = "SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR,$B$1,'Site Data '!$CU:$CU)"
```

I want this formula to go from C10:C25 and the $CU to go from CU:DJ. I can't seem to come up with a way to do this without creating a new line for each formula.

I would just do each one since it's only 16, but this is one of many sets of ranges that I need to update.

Comment: Does your `Sites` worksheet really have a trailing space in its name?

Comment: Haha yes, but right not that is the least of my issues. But I agree, I should change it sooner rather than later as I'll have to update whatever code I'm creating. I noticed it earlier this morning and am not sure how it happened (beyond user error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycle through the rows, adding the iteration var to the .Columns function and retrieve the address to concatenate into the formula.

```
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 10 To 25
        .Cells(i, "C").Formula = "=SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR, $B$1, 'Site Data '!" & _
            Worksheets("Site Data ").Columns(89 + i).Address & ")"
    Next i
End With
```

Btw, that formula could also be written as,

```
=SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR, $B$1, INDEX('Site Data '!$CU:$DJ, 0, ROW(1:1)))
```

Put in C10 and fill down or as,

```
.range("C10:C25").formula = _
    "=SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR, $B$1, INDEX('Site Data '!$CU:$DJ, 0, ROW(1:1)))"
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you for both giving me the right code as well as providing a simplification for my formula. Much appreciated!

Comment: I really wish I could give you more credit for this. Not only did you solve my problem, but your formula change actually made my calcs run a lot faster. Cheers mate!